# What was the real meaning behind the prediction Momoshiki made for Boruto's future?

Tags: boruto

As you know, Momoshiki once told to Boruto that:

> These blue eyes of yours would steal everything from you.

After reading the recent manga chapters, it feels like he meant something else. My question is:

> did he meant that Boruto would become his vessel or the prediction he made is still about to happen?